# What does unbound prefix mean, when parsing XML?

Tags: android-layout

I Have made a xml file in my android app for the Custom Widget and the error is:

> Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Here is my xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.CustomWidget.MyView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`com.example.CustomWidget` is the name of my package and `MyView` is the name of my class file where I made the custom `Widget`.

Comment: Which line is it complaining about? And why are you declaring the `xmlns:android` namespace twice?

Answer (score 24):

The second XML namespace is correct however it is the namespace of your custom widget so you need to define the name space appropriately:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

becomes:

```
xmlns:mynamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myproject.myprojectname"
```

Thereafter any custom attribute elements you define for your custom view will be referred to as:

```
mynamespace:my_defined_attribute="success"
```

instead of :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 5):

In your XML file, you have to add a line:

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.myproject.winedeals"
 .....
 .....>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the second XML Namespace declaration out:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <com.example.CustomWidget.MyView
     android:id="@+id/surface
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"  />
</LinearLayout>
```