# I have frequent error in android xml file under menu folder. Error parsing XML:unbound prefix

Tags: android

I have this error in menu_main.xml file under menu folder:

```
error:Error parsing XML unbound prefix.
```

my code is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: `app:showAsAction` and `appcompat:showAsAction`should be `android:showAsAction`

Comment: possible duplicate of [frequent problem in android view, Error parsing XML: unbound prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221221/frequent-problem-in-android-view-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329295/error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: R.java file cannot be generated after clean and build the project.

Answer (score 3):

Unbound prefix.  You should look at `android:`, `app:` and `appcompat:`.

This line

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

defines the namespace `android` (the "ns" of "xmlns").  `app` and `appcompat` need to be defined the same way.

Answer (score 3):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
      android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below solutions.

You see this error with an incorrect namespace, or a typo in the attribute. Like 'xmlns' is wrong, it should be xmlns:android

otherwise put full xml code.